# No route matches [GET] "/students/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a basic form using ROR. I met this problem when running my rails code. I tried so many solutions from the internet but still couldn't fix this problem. I think the problem is in the routes.rb file. Can you guys help me? and care to explain how routing works & when I need to write something in routes.rb? I'm a newbie to rails btw. and I'm using RubyMine IDE. Appreciate for any helps!

app/views/students/new.html.erb

```
<h1>SignUp</h1>
<hr>
<%= form_for @student do |f| -%>
  Firstname: <%= f.text_field :firstname %><br>
  Lastname: <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end -%>
```

app/controllers/students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
      redirect_to new_student_path
    end
  end

end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'students#index'
  resources: Student
end
```

Comment: If you run "rake routes" in your terminal do you see a students/new route?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
resources :students
```

You Give Wrong Route

Comment: I changed. But the problem still there. Can I know what is the difference? What should i put beside the "resouces" everytime? Because that is what I learn from the YouTube video, and i'm still don't understand.

Comment: if you write like resources :students than it'll allow route for create,new,edit,update,index,destroy,show automatically

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error with your routes. Your resource route should look like

```
resources :students
```

Note that you're passing the plural form of resource as a `symbol` to `resources` method.

This generates the following routes:

```
             students GET    /students(.:format)          students#index
                      POST   /students(.:format)          students#create
          new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)      students#new
         edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format) students#edit
              student GET    /students/:id(.:format)      students#show
                      PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
                      PUT    /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
                      DELETE /students/:id(.:format)      students#destroy
```

Comment: I changed. But the problem still there. Can I know what is the difference? What should i put beside the "resouces" everytime? Because that is what I learn from the YouTube video, and i'm still don't understand.

Comment: @GaryVlc, My solution will work cause it generates seven routes for CRUD operations on `student` objects. To know more,  see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html